# Control + F similar text search box to embed in website for iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

So I have a long iframe in my website full of text. **Iframe is from an other domain that I don't own so I have no control over this embedded iframe.** What I do when I want to search a part of text in this iframe is to click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and it will find the needed text and jump on that part of the iframe.

That was ok for as long as I used this page only for myself. Now that many people are accessing this iframe i can not explain the functionality of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to everybody. So I was thinking to embed a Text search in this page where the iframe is so it will be easier for people to find what they want.

I tried many suggestions by this site but they don't really work with iframe since they search words in the page where the iframe is embedded. **How <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> can detect text from iframe? Is it possible to have same functionality embedded in my website?**

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did this other day using only Javascript maybe not the most efficient as it reads and re-writes the inner html onkeyup (so i had to make some regex to ignore tags) but it works and is quick let me know if you have any improvements.
I tried to put it in codepen but as it f**ks with innerhtml so it doesnt work but this might be up for a while:http://longstone.rocks/Cinturato/fitment-guide/

Note---id:matches is a <\p> under my search telling the user how many matches it found

```
<script>
    function Search(){
        //clear everyting
        document.getElementById("matches").innerHTML = "Type to find your car!";
        document.getElementById("main-content").innerHTML = document.getElementById("main-content").innerHTML.replace(/<span.+?>(.+?)<\/span>/g,'$1');
        if (document.getElementById("textbox").value !== ""){
            alert();


        //this regegex basically matches all pattern exept from when its inbetween < and >
        var searchterm = ("(?<!</?[^>]*|&[^;]*)(" + document.getElementById("textbox").value + ")");
        var regex = new RegExp(searchterm,"gi");
        w3.addClass('textarea', 'w3-border-red');
        //if there is no match then it breaks in this following line when i want it to return 0 rather than break
        var numberOfMatches = document.getElementById("main-content").innerHTML.match(regex).length;
        alert(numberOfMatches);
        alert("fdfd");
        document.getElementById("main-content").innerHTML = document.getElementById("main-content").innerHTML.replace(regex,'<span class="w3-aqua">$1</span>');

        document.getElementById("matches").innerHTML = numberOfMatches + " Matches highlighted scroll to see matches";
        if(numberOfMatches !== 0)
            w3.removeClass('textarea', 'w3-border-red');

        }
        else
            w3.addClass('textarea', 'w3-border-red');


    }
</script>
```